# How can I connect one coolant pump to two power sources?

Tags: batteries

I am trying to figure out the final component of my camper electrical system and I have found I am stepping beyond the scope of "connect A to B" etc.

I have a diesel water heater with an auxiliary pump (12 V) which circulates hot water to where I need it. This comes with a wiring loom which will be connected to the leisure battery bank so it can be turned on and off using the supplied controller. This is fine, but what I would like to do is run that same pump from the starter battery when the engine is running. My plan was to just connect a  cable to the pump, but I'm starting to read things about diodes, surge protection, filtering and relays which has made me want some advice.

I understand the concept that a diode will stop the feeding of one into the other, but googling for such diodes has left me thinking there's still lots I don't know.

What may be best way or how do I approach buying the right thing? Ideally there is a product out there which I can just splice in with both supplies and the load, but I don't want to buy the wrong thing or bodge something together that causes problems down the line.

Comment: You are probably best asking this on https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Doesn't the leisure battery charge from the engine when it's running anyway? What you want may already be happening.

Comment: So it's not charging I want. It's control. I want to be able to run the pump while the engine is running. Without running the heater. The heater controls don't allow for this. Mechanically I could fit an auxillary pump but I feel that an electrical solution is better

Comment: If you just connect it to the starter battery, how will you turn it off when the engine isn't running? The starter battery still has power when the engine isn't running.

Comment: Welcome! Please draw a block diagram of all the parts you have and how they are connected today.

Comment: Yes I was being vague about the starter battery. But I would connect to a point that became live only when the engine was running. Maybe directly at the alternator in as I need to connect something else to there.

Answer (score 0):

A rule of thumb for long-term reliability of electronic components is 2x.  Use components rated for at least 2x the circuit requirement.  12 v circuit, 25 V diode/capacitor/whatever.  3 A motor, 6 A or 10 A diode.  8 W power dissipation in a resistor, 20 W part.  Etc.

We know the voltage, so you need diodes rated for a minimum of 25 V.  What is the rated current of the pump?  This sets the minimum current rating of the diodes (again, 2x to be safe).

Three diodes:  D7 and D8 in the image linked by Neil, plus one more across the motor for transient suppression.  You can bypass D9 and D10 because both of your power sources share a common return (GND).

Once you have your minimum numbers, go shopping.  There are automotive accessory sites that have diode kits packaged for vehicle wiring, or you can go to an electronics distributor like Digi-Key or Mouser, get the bare diodes, and wire them in yourself.

We know the voltage, so the current level sets the power dissipation in the diodes.  This might affect how you wire them in, using or not using shrink tubing, etc.